# creat a subplot [2,2]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, subplot

I'm trying to create a subplot of shape [2,2] with a pandas dataframe already created, but can´t find a solution.

Let's say I want the first plot inside one of the four plots. I feel I'm almost there, but still something is missing.

```py
c = hosts_df
c_country = c.groupby(['country', c['enviroment']]).size()
c_country.unstack()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].barh(['c_country.unstack()'])
axs[0, 0].set_title('Gráfico 3');`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.